# Интернет Debian в две Lan

Tags: сеть, debian, iptables, lan, squid

Есть устройство Negear M4300-52G, на нём настроены VLAN на каждый порт - разные.

10.10.1.0/24 - сеть серверов

10.10.10.0 - 10.10.200.0 - сеть цехов (пользовательские ПК)

**Есть сервер, в нём три сетевые карты:**

1) интернет 192.168.1.7 (роутер)

2) локальная сеть 192.168.0.123 получил сервер (старая сеть)

3) локальная сеть 10.10.1.4 (новая сеть VLAN)

С подсети 10.10.10.0/24 я могу пинговать 10.10.1.5 и 10.10.1.6 (другие сервера), а 10.10.1.4 не могу. Так же не могу пинговать с сервера 10.10.1.4 адрес в другой подсети 10.10.10.2

*Из подсети 10.10.1.0/24 адрес прокси-сервера 10.10.1.4 пингуется и интернет есть!*

Не могу понять что я не открыл на сервере (наверное)....

Вот наглядно как работает/не работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть iptables

```
#!/bin/bash

export IPT="iptables"

# Внешний интерфейс
export WAN=enp0s31f6
export WAN_IP=192.168.1.70
export WAN_RANGE=192.168.1.0/24

# Локальная сеть
export LAN=enp6s0
export LAN_IP=192.168.0.123
export LAN_RANGE=192.168.0.0/24

# Локальная новая сеть
export LAN_NG=enp10s0
export LAN_IP_NG=10.10.1.4
export LAN_RANGE_NG=10.10.0.0/16

# Очищаем правила
$IPT -F
$IPT -F -t nat
$IPT -F -t mangle
$IPT -X
$IPT -t nat -X
$IPT -t mangle -X

# Запрещаем все, что не разрешено
$IPT -P INPUT DROP
$IPT -P OUTPUT DROP
$IPT -P FORWARD DROP

# Разрешаем localhost и локалку
$IPT -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i $LAN -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i $LAN_NG -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o $LAN -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o $LAN_NG -j ACCEPT

# Разрешаем пинги
$IPT -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# Разрешаем все исходящие подключения сервера
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o $WAN -j ACCEPT
# Разрешаем все входящие подключения сервера
#$IPT -A INPUT -i $WAN -j ACCEPT

# разрешаем установленные соединения
$IPT -A INPUT -p all -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p all -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
#$IPT -A FORWARD -p all -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i $WAN -p all -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i $LAN -p all -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i $LAN_NG -p all -j ACCEPT
##$IPT -A FORWARD -i $WAN -o $LAN -p all -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
##$IPT -A FORWARD -i $LAN -o $WAN -p all -j ACCEPT

# Отбрасываем неопознанные пакеты
$IPT -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
$IPT -A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP

# Отбрасываем нулевые пакеты
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP

# Закрываемся от syn-flood атак
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP

# Блокируем доступ с указанных адресов
#$IPT -A INPUT -s 84.122.21.197 -j REJECT

# Разрешаем доступ из локалки наружу
$IPT -A FORWARD -i $LAN -o $WAN -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i $LAN_NG -o $WAN -j ACCEPT
# Закрываем доступ снаружи в локалку
$IPT -A FORWARD -i $WAN -o $LAN -j REJECT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i $WAN -o $LAN_NG -j REJECT

#$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $WAN -p tcp --dport 9443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.124:9443
# Пробрасываем внешний порты на локальный адрес и порты
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1565 -i ${WAN} -j DNAT --to $LAN_IP:1565
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 1565 -i ${WAN} -j DNAT --to $LAN_IP:1565
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -i ${WAN} -j DNAT --to $LAN_IP:80
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 80 -i ${WAN} -j DNAT --to $LAN_IP:80
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1565 -i ${WAN} -j DNAT --to $LAN_IP_NG:1565
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 1565 -i ${WAN} -j DNAT --to $LAN_IP_NG:1565
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -i ${WAN} -j DNAT --to $LAN_IP_NG:80
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 80 -i ${WAN} -j DNAT --to $LAN_IP_NG:80

$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN -p tcp -d $WAN_RANGE --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN -p tcp -d $WAN_RANGE --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN -p tcp -d $WAN_RANGE --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN_NG -p tcp -d $WAN_RANGE --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN_NG -p tcp -d $WAN_RANGE --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN_NG -p tcp -d $WAN_RANGE --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
#$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN -p tcp -d $WAN_RANGE --dport 9443 -j ACCEPT

#Перенаправление запросов для SQUID
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN_NG -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
#Перенаправление https запросов для SQUID
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3129
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN -p tcp --dport 8443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3129
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN_NG -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3129
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN_NG -p tcp --dport 8443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3129
##$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN -p tcp --dport 9443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3129
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN -p tcp --dport 8000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN_NG -p tcp --dport 8000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128

$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WAN -p tcp -d $WAN_RANGE --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source $WAN_IP
$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WAN -p tcp -d $WAN_RANGE --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source $WAN_IP
#$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WAN -p tcp -d $WAN_RANGE --dport 9443 -j SNAT --to-source $WAN_IP
$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WAN -p tcp -d $WAN_RANGE --dport 8443 -j SNAT --to-source $WAN_IP
$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WAN -p tcp -d $WAN_RANGE --dport 8000 -j SNAT --to-source $WAN_IP
#$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WAN -p tcp -d $LAN_BUM_RANGE --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.5
#$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WAN -p tcp -d $LAN_BUM_RANGE --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.5

# Включаем NAT
#$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WAN -s $LAN_RANGE -j MASQUERADE
$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WAN -s $LAN_RANGE -j SNAT --to-source $WAN_IP
$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WAN -s $LAN_RANGE_NG -j SNAT --to-source $WAN_IP

# открываем доступ к SSH из вне
$IPT -A INPUT -i $WAN -p tcp --dport 1565 -j ACCEPT

# открываем доступ к WEB-сайту из вне
$IPT -A INPUT -i $WAN -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i $WAN -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# открываем доступ к RDP из вне
$IPT -A INPUT -i $WAN -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i $WAN -p udp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT

# открываем доступ к TeamViewer из вне
$IPT -A INPUT -i $WAN -p tcp --dport 5938 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i $WAN -p udp --dport 5938 -j ACCEPT

#порт NTP сервера внутри сети
$IPT -A INPUT -s $LAN_RANGE -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT

#порт NTP сервера внутри новой сети
$IPT -A INPUT -s $LAN_RANGE_NG -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT

#порт DNS сервера внутри сети
$IPT -A INPUT -s $LAN_RANGE -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -s $LAN_RANGE -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

#порт DNS сервера внутри новой сети
$IPT -A INPUT -s $LAN_RANGE_NG -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -s $LAN_RANGE_NG -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

#порт SQUID сервера внутри сети
$IPT -A INPUT -s $LAN_RANGE -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -s $LAN_RANGE -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -s $LAN_RANGE -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3129 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -s $LAN_RANGE -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 3129 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -s $LAN_RANGE -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3130 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -s $LAN_RANGE -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 3130 -j ACCEPT

#порт SQUID сервера внутри новой сети
$IPT -A INPUT -s $LAN_RANGE_NG -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -s $LAN_RANGE_NG -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -s $LAN_RANGE_NG -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3129 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -s $LAN_RANGE_NG -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 3129 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -s $LAN_RANGE_NG -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3130 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -s $LAN_RANGE_NG -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 3130 -j ACCEPT

# Сохраняем правила
/sbin/iptables-save  > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Comment: `ip r l` покажите

Comment: `[root@localhost etc]# ip r l

default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s31f6 proto static metric 100

default via 10.10.1.254 dev enp10s0 proto static metric 101

10.10.1.0/24 dev enp10s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.1.4 metric 100

192.168.0.0/24 dev enp6s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.123 metric 100

192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.70 metric 100`

Comment: ну как я и предположил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте маршрут 10.10.0.0/16 (или 10.10.10.0/24) на ip роутера из подсети 10.10.1.0/24.

Или отключите интерфейс "1)".

На данный момент сервер отвечает вам через интерфейс "1)" с неожиданным для клиента адресом(192.168.1.7) вместо запрошенного 10.10.1.4.

Comment: Мне на IP роутера не надо, у меня интернет через SQUID раздаётся. Мне необходимо, чтобы просто из любой подсети был виден 10.10.1.4 (а то сейчас ни пинг, ни прокси естественно не работает)

Comment: так что ли?route add -net 10.10.0.0/16 gw 10.10.1.4

Comment: Интернет не причем. Надо написать маршрут на ту железку у которой есть адреса в 10.10.1.0 и 10.10.10.0 - это устройство называется роутер даже если оно сервер.

Comment: неа, не так. у 10.10.1.4 нет маршрута до 10.10.10.0. там должно быть 10.10.1.1 или врое того

Comment: 10.10.1.254 - DHCP и шлюз, а 10.10.1.1 - DNS, тогда получается route add -net 10.10.0.0/16 gw 10.10.1.254

А вместо добавления `ip route add`, может можно прописать в iptables?

Comment: Только как прописать маршрут, чтобы после перезагрузки он сохранился? Я добавил файлик в `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` с названием `rule-enp10s0` и содержанием `10.10.0.0/16 via 10.10.1.254 dev enp10s0`. Но после перезагрузки маршрут не добавился....

Comment: Sysconfig вроде не дебиановская тема. ifup.d я использую в дебиане при, есть хуки в системд и можно прописать в нетворк менеджере. post-up в нетворк/интерфейсес